# Error on tf.keras.layers.Reshape. TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I use the 'Reshape' function in my code, there is a error about the source code. It was OK before. I have tried to reinstall Anaconda but it doesn't work. So I don't know how to fix it.
Here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-580b80167b50>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/py/dg_seg/dg_seg.py', wdir='F:/py/dg_seg')

  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "F:/py/dg_seg/dg_seg.py", line 95, in <module>
    dg=dg_seg()

  File "F:/py/dg_seg/dg_seg.py", line 43, in dg_seg
    pc_ = layers.Reshape((NUM_POINT,1,3))(pc)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\core.py", line 412, in __init__
    super(Reshape, self).__init__(**kwargs)

TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not function
```

The source code is:

```
@keras_export('keras.layers.Reshape')
class Reshape(Layer):
    def __init__(self, target_shape, **kwargs):
        super(Reshape, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.target_shape = tuple(target_shape)
```

Comment: Maybe you've created a function called `Reshape` that shadowed the class' name?

Comment: There is no other function.  I have tried it in a very simple file. But the error still occurs. And I don't know what happen to the library.

Comment: Could you please (1) show what `dg_seg.py` contains, so that we can have a better understanding of the contect and (2) tell us what versions are you using (python, tensorflow, keras, etc.)

Comment: I simply describe the file `dg_seg.py`. It is a neural network that I rewrite from others code. But that's not the point. There is still the error when I use the `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` in other files. The versions are python 3.6, tensorflow 2.0 on windows. I've also tried to reinstall tensorflow but it doesn't work.

Comment: This error occurred after I forced the shutdown while I was training the network.

Comment: I wanna know how to repair the library.

Comment: Wait it was once playing and after the shutdown it got "corrupted" somehow? I've never seen this happen before...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when trying to restore an exported model in .h5/savedmodel format that used a tf.keras.layers.Reshape layer using tensorflow==2.2.*. For anyone else trying to get around this error when restoring a model I was able to restore my model by exporting to savedmodel format and calling:

`tf.saved_model.load`

instead of

`tf.keras.models.load_model`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
@keras_export('keras.layers.Reshape')
class Reshape(Layer):
    def __init__(self, target_shape, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.target_shape = tuple(target_shape)
```

Difference is that we are not passing any args to `super` and also ensure that you have `*args` is there in `__init__` to keep actual functions definitions intact.